# How to set css rules for combination of class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div tag as

```
<div class="one two three">foo<div>
<div class="one two four">bar</div>
```

i am setting the css by using javascript,I can set styles as

```
.one.two.three{color:red;}
.one.two.four{color:blue;}
```

But can any one tell me how can i use `$(.class).css({"color":"blue"});` for combination of class

Comment: `$(".one.two.four").css({"color":"blue"});` – what's the problem?

Comment: @user3567511 show it in a http://jsfiddle.net, Shai's solution in comment should work

Comment: Sorry Guys Shai's solution is correct. I was going wrong with case sensitivity.

Answer (score 2):

1. **Make sure you have loaded jQuery**, as the `$(selector).css(...)` function you say you'd like to use is jQuery-specific.

   ```
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   ```
2. **Set the style** – making sure to wait until **the DOM is ready** before you try manipulating the styles:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function() {
           $(".one.two.four").css({"color":"blue"});
       });
   </script>
   ```

You can read all about everything I've described in [the jQuery Getting Started guide](http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/getting-started/).

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4b2n97hq/

If something isn't working, [open your browser's console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) and look for error messages that will help work out the problem.

Answer (score 1):

same as with css selector:

```
$('.one.two.three').css({"color":"blue"});
```

will select all elements that have all 3 classes.

You can also select just by the classes they have in common:

```
$('.one.two').css({"color":"blue"});
```

check this [fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/31huvykt/)